# How to convert this code to MIPS?

Tags: mips

#### C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int sum = 0;

    cout << " Enter a number : ";
    cin >> num;

    while ( num > 0 ) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```

How to convert this to MIPS?

I know, I can use the `$HI` and `$LO` registers but I am having trouble implementing this.

```
.data 
error: .asciiz "The Number you entered is not valid"
input: .asciiz "Please enter a number"

.text 

main:
#GET NUMBER FROM USER
li $v0, 4 #load syscall print string
la $a0, input  #load adress of str1 into $a0
syscall   #make the syscall

#SAVE NUMBER
li $v0, 5 #load syscall read_int into $v0
syscall   #make the syscall
move $s0, $v0 #move the number read into $t0 now $t0=n

#make sure number is between 100 and 400
addi $t1, $zero, 400
addi $t2, $zero, 100 
ble $s0, $t2, EXIT 
bge $s0, $t1, EXIT 



loop: 
div $s0, $s1 
add $s2, $s2, $LO 
add $s0, $HI, $zero 
bgt $s0, $zero, loop 




end: 
li $v0, 10 
syscall


EXIT: 
li $v0, 4 #load syscall print string
la $a0, error  #load adress of error into $a0
syscall   #make the syscall
```

Comment: Please, provide what you have tried.

Comment: Okay so like I said new to MIPS so my attempts are pretty futile. So the number that is inputted has to be between 100 and 400. Here is what I have tried but I am stuck in L1

Comment: Nothing wrong with failure attempts. If you have all success attempts, then  why would you ask something here? Just make sure you have tried something.

Answer (score 1):

When you do div in MIPS, the quotient goes into `$HI` and the remainder goes into `$LO`. If the while loop is what you are having issues with, that should help.

```
Sum: s2
Num: s0
10: s1

While:      # while num >0
div $s0, $s1. #  $s0/$s1    num/10
add $s2, $s2, $LO # sum += num%10
add $s0, $HI, $zero   # num /= 10
bgt $s0, $zero, While # if num >0 loop again
```

The rest is just a loop with branch greater than.

Comment: would the branch greater than be to check to make sure the $HI is greater than 0?

Comment: Should be to check if the register your num is saved in is after it stores it, so it would check if it is greater thn zero, and if so jump back into the loop

Comment: alright yeah i am having a really hard time wrapping my head around this for some reason

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, some concepts are hard to understand at first

Comment: let me re edit the code I have up there and see if we can go from there

Comment: also sorry if I got rid of an edit up there this is my first post on the website trying to figure out the interface

Comment: Okay that loop you wrote I now fully understand and it makes sense to me. Now I need to move onto printing the result